# Converting matlab matrix to fortran 90

Tags: matlab, matrix, fortran

If I have a matlab `(n,3)` matrix which corresponds to `x`,`y`,`z` coordinates, how would I be able to take that matrix from matlab and transfer it to fortran 90 format?

I've tried saving the variable from matlab and then doing:

```
implicit none 

double precision coord(22323,3)
open(unit=11,file='coord.dat',access='stream',form='unformatted')
read(11) coord

end program kal
```

But I get trigger breakpoint at `read(11) coord`. I've also tried saving it as a `.bin` file and had the same issue.

Just to be clear I'm not talking about using `mex` I'm just trying to transfer the data into a variable in fortran.

Comment: Yuu should really also show us your Matlab exporting code and the content of the data file.

Comment: checkout the documentation from matlab: [link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/Fortran-applications-to-read-mat-file-data.html?searchHighlight=read%20matlab%20file%20in%20fortran&s_tid=srchtitle).

Comment: Maybe dimension it as (2,3) and writing out the results working through 'stream; and 'direct' etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this could be hard with a binary file, unless Matlab has a specific function for writing Fortran-compatible files. I would just write it to a space-separated text-file. Then you need to loop through the file like

```
open(unit=11,file='coord.dat')
do i = 1,22323
  read(11) coord(i,:)
enddo
close(11)
```

I don't think using a text-file will create much overhead for this amount of data unless you do it very many times.